# Problem with chaining many small DMX cables

Tags: cables, dmx

In DMX cables (used for lights), all cables are daisy-chained.

In my band we are normally on small stages, but occasionally on bigger.

To prevent buying very long cables, I wonder if it is a good idea to buy multiple 5 m (or yard) cables and just connect them together (without a DMX device in between) in case we need longer length.

I assume it is not a problem, but just wondering.

There is some 'common' used maximum of like 10-15 fixtures, but does this count the number of DMX devices or the number of 'cable connections'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a maximum rule of 32 devices and 1800 feet (548m) of cable in a single chain, though generally people seem to aim for about half that number of devices in practice. Each connector you add in will have an impact on the maximum length because of the resistance it adds in.

I doubt that you'll have any problem with multiple extensions unless you're talking about hundreds of metres. Even so, I'd be inclined to go with longer extensions (10m or even 25m) and less of them - there will be fewer connections to fail.

Comment: I know it is better to also have longer extensions, but probably we will barely use the 25m barely almost never, and buying 2 cables of 10 m (and/or adding 5m) will do ... we also don't want excessive lengths of cables on/around the stage. So in case we need long distances (like 20-25 m) I intended to just add another 10 m to an existing 10m

Comment: I cannot imagine we will ever have more than like 20 devices, all within a maximum 8x8m environment and except for exceptions all grouped by 4 (on a stand).

Comment: Then I can't see that you're ever going to have any problems.